# Error inflating class com.wikitude.architect.ArchitectView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, runtime-error, wikitude

I am using Android studio with Epson Wikitude's SDK. When I run the application it crashes and I am getting an inflate class error. I have looked at several other questions, but none of the was quite the same or worked for my problem.

```
/com.example.username.myapplication E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering /
    com.example.username.myapplication E / AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: load_library[1091]: Library '/data/data/com.example.pmbi002.myapplication/libarchitect.so'
not found
at java.lang.Runtime.load(Runtime.java: 340)
at java.lang.System.load(System.java: 524)
at com.wikitude.architect.ArchitectView.e(Unknown Source)
at com.wikitude.architect.ArchitectView.a(Unknown Source)
at com.wikitude.architect.ArchitectView. < init > (Unknown Source)
at com.wikitude.architect.ArchitectView. < init > (Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java: 417) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java: 586) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java: 680) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java: 739) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java: 489) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java: 396) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java: 352) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java: 280) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java: 140) 
at com.example.pmbi002.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java: 30) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java: 4465) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java: 1049) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java: 1920) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java: 1981) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java: 123) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java: 1147) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java: 99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java: 137) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java: 4424) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java: 511) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java: 784) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java: 551) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Build.gradle file:**

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

   android {
       compileSdkVersion 15
       buildToolsVersion '22.0.0'
       defaultConfig {
           applicationId "com.example.myusername.myapplication"
           minSdkVersion 11
           targetSdkVersion 15
           versionCode 1
           versionName "1.0"
       }
       buildTypes {
           release {
               minifyEnabled false
               proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
           }
       }
       productFlavors {}
   }

   dependencies {
       compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
       testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
       compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v4:22.0.0'
       compile 'com.android.support:design:22.0.0'
   }
```

Comment: The important line of the error code is "Cannot load library: load_library[1091]: Library '/data/data/com.example.pmbi002.myapplication/libarchitect.so' not found". This is the application not being able to load a native library that I'm assuming should be provided by the sdk you're integrating. The reason it comes up as an inflate error is because that is when the library is being loaded, so it appears like the inflation failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android studio expects the native libraries to be at the lib folder inside the jar while they are in the libs folder so android studio can't find them.

What you can do to fix this is:

- make a copy of the jar
- unzip it extract the libs folder
- rename libs to lib and zip the lib folder
- rename the new .zip to .jar

and import it in your gradle file:

```
dependencies{
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar’)
}
```

This fixed it for me.
It was also described in the wikitude forum: http://www.wikitude.com/developer/developer-forum/-/message_boards/message/858620#_19_message_858823

Edit:
You can also try to

- set classpath ‘com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0’ to ‘com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0’ in build.gradle from your project
- make sure the compileSdkVersion, targetSdkVersion  and com.android.support-v4 are 22 or lower

This should not be a problem because the Epson Moverio BT-200 runs on Android 15

Edit: 
This gradle setup solved the problem for me:
/app/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.wikitude.sdksamples"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}
```

project build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

As i mentioned in the comments, there is an Wikitude Epson SDK update coming soon which should get rid of the complications with android studio.

Comment: I followed those steps and now have a wikitudesdk.jar file and a lib.jar file at C:\Users\username\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\libs             but when I try to sync the project it says it gives me the following error. Thanks.                                                                                                 Error:(22, 0) Cannot invoke method compile() on null object
<a href="openFile:C:\Users\pmbi002\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build.gradle">Open File</a>

Comment: do you have "repositories {
    flatDir{
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
" in your build.gradle?

Comment: yes, I do. I will copy my build.gradle file above. I also tried changing the file inside wikitudesdk to lib and rezipping that file. That leaves me with just the wikitudesdk.jar file, but results in the same error.

Comment: can you edit your post to show me your build.gradle file?

Comment: Quick guess would be that compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0' is defined outside of dependencies. Try "dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
}"

Comment: Woops I'm not sure how that happened. I fixed that, but I still get a build error when I try to follow the steps from the above answer.                                                                                                             \MainActivity.java
Error:(16, 30) error: package com.wikitude.architect does not exist
Error:(21, 13) error: cannot find symbol class ArchitectView
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: try Syncing Project with Gradle Files

Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't seem to do change much. I added my edited wikitudesdk to archive. So now it is just wikitudesdk.jar. I now have the build erros in previous comment  plus this one:                                                                                                    Error:error reading C:\Users\username\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\libs\wikitudesdk.jar; error in opening zip file
meout.)
<a href="syncProject">Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)</a>
<a href="syncProject">Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)</a>

Comment: Your build.gradle looks good, i just tried it with my app and it works. Also you can't just edit the folder inside the jar and re-zip it this causes the error you described.

Comment: Okay, I copied wikitudesdkjar, extracted the copy, removed the libs folder, changed libs to lib, zipped it, and named it lib.jar. when I am done I have the original unedited wikitudesdkjar file and the lib.jar file in the folder. The project builds, but it runs with the same original inflate error.

Comment: I really appreciate your suggestions. Perhaps this could give you more insight on the possible problem. When I run the program, It shows  warnings that say Could not find method and unable to resolve virtual method. and errors that say  Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable' and Binary XML file line #34: Error inflating class com.wikitude.architect.ArchitectView. Thanks.

Comment: Is your folder structure MyApplication/app/libs/ and in this folder you have lib.jar and wikitudesdk.jar? lib.jar contains lib/armrabi/libwikitude.so and your app/build.gradle stil looks like the one in your post?

Comment: Yes. All of my files match that and I have not changed the build gradle.

Comment: I tried the same way as described with your gradle file and the set-up worked without any errors. Saying that, we’re releasing an updated Epson SDK within the next weeks which is based on Android Studio.

Comment: Would if be possible for you to share your working project on GitHub?Thanks

Comment: There is one more thing you could try:
 * set classpath ‘com.android.tools.build:***’ to ‘com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0’ in build.gradle from your project
* make sure the compileSdkVersion, targetSdkVersion  and com.android.support-v4 are 22 or lower

Comment: I am trying to set support-v4 to 22, but it gives me an error saying failed to resolve. I have made sure android support repository was installed. I have posted the  updated build.gradle above. Thanks

Comment: I posted my working gradle setup, could you try to build your app using it?

Comment: I copied the build gradle files and now get the following build errors: values-v21\styles.xml
No resource found that matches the given names BELOW: attr 'windowActionBar'.
 attr 'windowNoTitle'.
 attr 'windowActionBar'.
 attr 'windowNoTitle'.  'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
 attr 'colorAccent'.
: attr 'colorPrimary'.
 attr 'colorPrimaryDark'.
'ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar'.
 'ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light'.

Comment: try adding "compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0' " to dependencies

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate all your assistance. I got the app running.